# Page caches eat RAM and vmpressure

Tags: linux, memory, android

The bottom line is a situation when Linux kernel eat about all available RAM that we have (and I do understand that it's completely OK, and that memory still available and can be reclaimed: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) but even before that Linux kernel triggers vmpressure event that Android is using to detect OOM situation and starting killing user processes.

I faced with that problem specifically in Android 9 and linux kernel:

```
Linux version 4.14.65-tcc (dimorinny@dimorinny-pc) (gcc version 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease) (GCC)) #6 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 16:47:48 MSK 2020
```

Maybe someone knows, why Linux is considering that situation as memory pressure and triggers that event? Maybe there is a way to force Linux to reclaim file-backed caches before vm pressure events?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a general Linux issue and it surely looks like the issue with how your particular Android ROM is set up.

The Linux kernel by default will absolutely reclaim buffers/caches to allow new processes to run without killing the already running ones or paging stuff out.